# Should you keep the (encrypted) gpg secret key in a file to export the password store on another machine?

Tags: password, gpg, gpg-agent

I am using `gpg` and `pass` to manage my password (on my Macos). I want to read the keychain contained in `.password-store` on another machine.

As there was no public or private key listed in the gpg on the linux machine, I exported both of them inside the `.password-store` with the following command:

```
gpg --output gpg_pub_key --export <Email address>
gpg --output gpg_sec_key --export-secret-keys <Email address>
```

And on the linux machine imported the key from the copied `.password-store` with the following command:

```
gpg --import gpg_pub_key
gpg --import gpg_sec_key
```

(Following the answer from @SD3 in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321712/gpg-decryption-fails-with-no-secret-key-error)

I then regularly backup my `.password-store` on a external hardrive / NAS or even sometime copy `.password-store` on an external usb drive

My question: is it safe to the public key file `gpg_pub_key` and the private key file `gpg_sec_key` inside the `.password-store`?
IF THIS IS NOT SAFE AND I SHOULD DELETE THEM: then what would be the strategy to have decrypt the files inside `.password-store` without having exported the public key file `gpg_pub_key` and the private key file `gpg_sec_key`?

Many thanks in advance